# What functions in the GNU C runtime library are in the standard library?

Tags: c, gnu

How do I find out what CRT functions supported by GNU C are part of the standard library?  As an example: atoi() and itoa().

Comment: Are you testing us? Easily could be found in the net sources.

Comment: @Artem Barger: Yep, Google search, second result: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/1057/

Comment: The Wikipedia [itoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itoa) and [atoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atoi) articles provide the answer.

Comment: Yuck, there could be hundreds more versions of this question.  Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atoi()` is part of the standard library.
`itoa()` is not part of the standard library.

---

<strike>You can implement it this way to use it:</strike>

```
 #include <string.h>

 void itoa(int input, void (*subr)(char));

 void itoa(int n, char s[]) {
     int i, sign;

     if ((sign = n) < 0)  /* record sign */
         n = -n;          /* make n positive */
     i = 0;
     do {       /* generate digits in reverse order */
         s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';   /* get next digit */
     } while ((n /= 10) > 0);     /* delete it */
     if (sign < 0)
         s[i++] = '-';
     s[i] = '\0';
     reverse(s);
 }


 /* reverse:  reverse string s in place */
 void reverse(char s[]) {
     int i, j;
     char c;

     for (i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i<j; i++, j--) {
         c = s[i];
         s[i] = s[j];
         s[j] = c;
     }
 }
```

See comments to see why this is striked through, although it works fine for other values.

Comment: You just need to check for INT_MIN: `itoa(INT_MIN, buffer); /* oops */`

Comment: @pmg you are right hehe: http://codepad.org/NMgMOMqC same for `INT_MAX` only it'll result in a crash :( http://codepad.org/1hjOxqJb

Comment: for `INT_MAX` there is no problem. I changed the buffer in your code and run it: http://codepad.org/KldCWIbP

Answer (score 2):

Quoting part of Wikipedia's first paragraphs for each of `atoi` and `itoa`:

### [`atoi`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atoi)

`atoi` **is a function in the C programming language** that converts a string into an integer numerical representation. atoi stands for ASCII to integer. **It is included in the C standard library header file stdlib.h**.

### [`itoa`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itoa)

The `itoa` (integer to ASCII) function is a widespread **non-standard** extension to the standard C programming language. It cannot be portably used, as **it is not defined in any of the C language standards**; however, compilers often provide it through the header  while in non-conforming mode, because it is a logical counterpart to the standard library function `atoi`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is rather obviously perhaps to use a standard library reference. The definitive reference is the ISO standard.  But there are others The [Dinkumware C Library](http://www.dinkumware.com/c99.aspx) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that at least atoi() is in the std library.

Wikipedia confirms it [atoi()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atoi) [itoa()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itoa)

Answer (score 0):

`itoa` is not in standard library../

Answer (score 0):

`itoa` is not part of the standard library; it is a common extension.

`atoi` is part of the standard library, and its prototype is declared in `stdlib.h` ([n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), § 7.20.1.2).

For a complete listing of what functions are part of the standard library, see the online C standard, draft [n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), § 7 (Library).